# Why does my SwitchPreference glitch on orientation change?

Tags: java, android, android-preferences, android-switch

I have an activity (extends AppCompatActivity) that contains a `PreferenceFragment` with my app's settings. The first setting is a SwitchPreference to enable or disable notifications, followed by other preferences that depend upon that SwitchPreference.

My problem is this: I discovered that if I rotate the device (causing an orientation change) and then tap the switch, it doesn't render properly - it seems to show two overlapping switches ([here's a screencap from a Moto X](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xs2i1.png)), one in the old position and one in the new position. Interestingly, this even happens with the older style of switches ([here's a screencap from a Nexus S running JellyBean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ScWj.png)).

I haven't found anything about this bug around the internet, and as far as I can tell, it doesn't happen in Android OS apps (such as Settings) or in other third-party apps (such as Intent Intercept by Intrications). So it seems I'm just doing something wrong here.

Here is the setup code in my SettingsFragment:

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);

        // Grab Preference objects
        final Preference wklyRemPref = findPreference(getString(R.string.prefkey_weekly_reminder));

        // Set up notification settings
        findPreference(getString(R.string.prefkey_allow_notifs))
                .setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
                        if (Boolean.FALSE.equals(newValue)) {
                            // Turn off and disable "Weekly Reminder" pref
                            ((TwoStatePreference) wklyRemPref).setChecked(false);
                            // (Disabling is done by the system because the "Weekly Reminder"
                            // preference depends on the "Notifications" preference)
                        }
                        return true;
                    }
                });
        wklyRemPref.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
                Log.d("Pref", preference + " value changed (" + newValue + ")");
                return true;
            }
        });
        ...
    }
```

Here is my `settings.xml` file:

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <PreferenceCategory android:title="Reminders">
        <SwitchPreference
            android:defaultValue="true"
            android:key="@string/prefkey_allow_notifs"
            android:title="@string/allow_notifs"/>
        <!-- Weekly reminder: -->
        <CheckBoxPreference
            android:dependency="@string/prefkey_allow_notifs"
            android:defaultValue="true"
            android:key="@string/prefkey_weekly_reminder"
            android:summary="Remind me weekly to choose a scripture"
            android:title="Weekly reminder" />
        <net.danmercer.ponderizer.settings.ReminderPreference
            android:defaultValue="sunday/17:00"
            android:dependency="@string/prefkey_weekly_reminder"
            android:key="@string/prefkey_weekly_reminder_time"
            android:title="Set weekly reminder time" />
        <!-- Notification preferences -->
        <RingtonePreference
            android:dependency="@string/prefkey_allow_notifs"
            android:key="@string/prefkey_notif_sound"
            android:title="Notification Sound"
            android:ringtoneType="notification"
            android:showDefault="true"
            android:showSilent="true"/>
        <CheckBoxPreference
            android:defaultValue="true"
            android:dependency="@string/prefkey_allow_notifs"
            android:key="@string/prefkey_notif_vibrate"
            android:title="Vibrate" />
    </PreferenceCategory>
    ...
</PreferenceScreen>
```

**Edit:**
I have also tried to clean and rebuild my project, and uninstall and reinstall the app, to no avail.

Edit 2:
I tried using a CheckBoxPreference instead of a SwitchPreference and experienced the same problem. And what's worse, I discovered that the entire fragment seems to be burned into the screen (so to speak) when I rotate the activity. I can scroll the settings fragment, but a ghost of what it was before stays behind. This artifact manifested earlier as two overlapping switches, but I didn't realize it was so pervasive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. In my SettingsActivity onCreate() method, I had code like this:

```
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
fm.beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.frag_container, new SettingsFragment())
        .commit();
```

I changed the `replace()` call to an `add()` call, and now it works properly. It seems that **the activity was adding two identical fragments to the layout** when it was recreated upon orientation change. Using replace solved the problem, because it wouldn't add multiple fragments to the activity. Moral of the story: when in doubt, use `replace()`, not `add()`.